# plt.plot: X axis problem when plotting line in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, types, x-axis

i encounter a problem when plotting the graph in Python using plt.

The X axis value didnt match the index value at all and start from zero, i would like the x axis show 2009-03/2009-04 etc instead of starting from zero.

Here is my data table

[image]
[image]

```
plt.figure()

plt.plot(WTS_summary.values,linewidth=1,alpha = 0.7,c='salmon')
plt.xlabel("X-Axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-Axis")
```

The plot looks like this

[image]

Thanks a lot...i had been stack on this for a long time even i try other plotting method

After suggestion it still show Error. Thank You Himalaya Bir Shrestha

[image]

Comment: You need to explicitly pass the x values.

Comment: The screenshots are hard to read

Answer (score 0):

Can you add following line:

```
plt.xticks(ticks=np.arange(0,len(WTS_summary)), labels=WTS_summary.index))
```

You need to import numpy first for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However it show errors.                                                                   
 AttributeError: Unknown property ticks